# Limit MAX() result to one row based on highest value in a particular field

Tags: sql, oracle

Of course my data set is more complex, but this is essentially what I have:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| SEQ_NO | FILTER | VALUE |
+--------+--------+-------+
|      1 | 'A'    |     5 |
|      2 | 'A'    |    10 |
|      3 | 'A'    |    15 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO)
       , FILTER
       , VALUE
    FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FILTER
       , VALUE
```

This returns my entire data set. How can I alter my query so that it only returns the record with the highest SEQ_NO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12C:

```
SELECT SEQ_NO
       , FILTER
       , VALUE
    FROM TABLE
 ORDER BY SEQ_NO DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) MAXSeq
           , FILTER
           , VALUE
        FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY FILTER
           , VALUE
) t2  ON t1.SEQ_NO = t2.MAXSeq 
        AND t1.FILTER = t2.FILTER 
        AND t1.VALUE = t2.VALUE
```

Or using `row_number`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *, 
     row_number() over(partition by FILTER, VALUE 
                       order by SEQ_NO desc) as rn
   FROM table
) t 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the top SEQ_NO per filter?

i've created this in SQL Server and converted to Oracle

```
SELECT  a.SEQ_NO,
        a.FILTER,
        a.VALUE
FROM    (
            SELECT  SEQ_NO,
                    FILTER,
                    VALUE,
                    MAX(SEQ_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY FILTER) m
            FROM    TABLE
        ) a
WHERE   SEQ_NO = m
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql

```
SELECT SEQ_NO
       , VALUE
       , FILTER
    FROM TABLE
Order by SEQ_NO DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: using mysql in a question with oracle tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROWNUM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) in oracle:

```
select *
from  
  ( select * 
    from yourTable
    order by SEQ_NO desc )  as t
where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY SEQ_NO DESC
```